Cloudinary Upload Widget does not process more than 1 image
I attempted to use the Cloudinary Upload Widget to upload multiple photo. However, it is only processing a single image. and failing to appear. but every image was uploaded to Cloudinary.it and also images are not get into form value.only 1 image showing in the value.
widget photo
image photo
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="images"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>Product Image</FormLabel>
                <h3>{field.value.length}</h3>
                <FormControl>
                  <ImageUpload
                    value={field.value.map((image) => image.url)}
                    disabled={loading}
                    onChange={(url) =>
                      field.onChange([...field.value, { url }])
                    }
                    onRemove={(url) =>
                      field.onChange([
                        ...field.value.filter((image) => image.url !== url),
                      ])
                    }
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />

 <div className="mb-4 flex items-center gap-4">
        {value.map((url) => (
          <div
            key={url}
            className="relative size-[200px] overflow-hidden rounded-md"
          >
            <div className="absolute right-2 top-2 z-10">
              <Button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => onRemove(url)}
                variant="destructive"
                size="icon"
              >
                <Trash className="size-4" />
              </Button>
            </div>
            <Image
              className="object-cover"
              src={url}
              alt="Image"
              width={200}
              height={200}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <CldUploadWidget uploadPreset="u3lcombs" onSuccess={onUpload}>
        {({ open }) => {
          const onClick = () => {
            open();
          };

          return (
            <Button
              type="button"
              disabled={disabled}
              variant="secondary"
              onClick={onClick}
            >
              <ImagePlus className="mr-2 size-4" />
              Upload an Image
            </Button>
          );
        }}
      </CldUploadWidget>
    </div>


The onQueuesEnd event can be used to get information about all files processed by the API. You can get the processed file information in the onSuccess event and store it in a global variable. You may check out this documentation for more samples.

you need to add the multiple parameter as true - see here
options={{
  multiple: true,
}}

https://next.cloudinary.dev/clduploadwidget/configuration#options-1
